# ¿Como converit String a date en Golang?

Tags: date, go

Hola a todos de ante mano, muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios.
Quiero lograr lo siguente tengo una fecha la cual obtengo de la base de datos con el siguiente formato esta fecha es un string y la guardo en lavariable date:

```
date := "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Quiero transformar dicha fecha al tipo de dato date para extraer el año con la función YEAR(), que me qude algo como lo siguiente:

```
date := "2015-02-01"
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
    newDate, error := time.Parse("2022-02-01", date)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }
    println("año", date.Year())
```

Sin embargo esto me devuelve un 1 y deberia devolverme 2015, imprimiendo el parseo me devuelve esto:

```
parsing time "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z" as "2022-02-01": cannot parse "-02-01T00:00:00Z" as "2"
```

si imprimo la variable date después del parseo veo que me devuelve esto:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Creo que lo que esta generando el error son los segundos, minutos y horas en mi string pero no se como solucionarlo.

Comparto liga a Go Playground:
[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Sb2xQLuL3hw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hace falta hacer ese trim manual, simplemente puedes especificar el formato al método `Parse()` en tu caso sería `RFC3339`, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
date := "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z"

anniversary, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Could not parse time:", err)
}

fmt.Println(anniversary)
fmt.Println(anniversary.Year())
```

puedes ver todos los formatos soportados en [la documentación](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) de Go.

Answer (score 2):

La solución a mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Como tenemos un string con el siguiente formato

```
date := "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es eliminar "T00:00:00Z", eso lo logramos con el siguiente código

```
temporalDate := strings.TrimSuffix(date, "T00:00:00Z")
```

Hasta este punto nuestra variable sigue siendo un string si queremos tener acceso a las funciones del paquete time, toca parsear el string a un date

```
anniversary, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", temporalDate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
```

Y con esto ya tenemos acceso a métodos del paquete time por ejemplo:

```
anniversary.Year()
```